One attribute is not transferred when passing an object to the backend, while others are
I am trying to make an E-Commerce Website and am using Angular for the frontend and SpringBoot for the backend.
When a purchase is made, I want to save the details of the purchase in the database( I'm using MySQL).
So once a purchase is done, the angular code passes a "purchase" object through POST to the backend where my spring-boot controller receives the purchase object and extracts the necessary information.
The issue is that, even though the object has 4 properties, i,e, customer, address, order, and orderItems,  the address always shows up as null.
This is my angular service code which sends the purchase object -
export class CheckoutService {

  private purchaseUrl = "http://localhost:8080/api/checkout/purchase";

  constructor(public httpClient: HttpClient) { }

  placeOrder(purchase: Purchase): Observable<any> {
    return this.httpClient.post<Purchase>(this.purchaseUrl, purchase); 
  }

}

I have verified that the purchase object does contain the address data at this point.
Here is my Springboot controller code -
@CrossOrigin("http://localhost:4200")
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/checkout")
public class CheckoutController {

    private CheckoutService checkoutService;

    @Autowired
    public CheckoutController(CheckoutService checkoutService) {
        this.checkoutService = checkoutService;
    }

    @PostMapping("/purchase")
    public PurchaseResponse placeOrder(@RequestBody Purchase purchase){

        PurchaseResponse purchaseResponse = checkoutService.placeOrder(purchase);
        System.out.println(purchase);

        return purchaseResponse;
    }

}

Here, when the purchase object is checked, the address is always null. The other fields all perfectly work.
Classes Purchase and Address in Angular -
export class Purchase {

    customer! : Customer;
    address! : Address;
    order! : Order;
    orderItems!: OrderItem[];

}


export class Address {
    
    street! : string;
    city! : string;
    state! : string;
    country! : string;
    zipCode! : string;

}

Classes Purchase and Address in SpringBoot-
@Data
public class Purchase {

    private Customer customer;
    private Address shippingAddress;
    private Order order;
    private Set<OrderItem> orderItems;

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "address")
@Getter
@Setter
public class Address {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "street")
    private String street;

    @Column(name = "city")
    private String city;

    @Column(name = "state")
    private String state;

    @Column(name = "country")
    private String country;

    @Column(name = "zip_code")
    private String zipCode;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "shippingAddress")
    private Order order;
}



Your property is shippingAddress not address, it doesn't match so it is ignored by Angular. Either change the client or the server so the names match.

Oh you're right @M.Deinum. Thanks man! I completely looked past that

So this question is resolved? :)

Yes.How do I close the question?
